# Odd error when trying to convert leads

Tags: lead-conversion

Trying to convert a lead and get the generic error

[image]

What's odd is that if I created a clone of this lead, assign it to the same person and then try to convert the clone, it works.

That means converting does work, so I have to rule out field mapping, validation rules, some process flow or workflow rule preventing it and pretty much most options.

What's left?

Comment: Are you in a partialcopy or fullcopy sandbox?

Comment: No I'm in the production org.

Comment: Do you have a trigge on lead,account and contact? Such error can be manually added in Trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realistically, there's no One True Fix for this problem. It depends on what's going on under the hood. To figure out what's going on, click on "Your Name > Developer Console", click on the Logs tab, and try your conversion again. At this point, a new log should show up; open it up by double-clicking.

The default settings should probably be enough to give you an inkling as to what's going on, but if you need to change the debug levels, you can change them by clicking on Debug > Change Log Levels, then under General Trace Settings For You, click on Add/Change on the DEVELOPER_LOG line, click Add to add a new entry, set the debug levels you want, click Done to set the new debug log level, click Done again to set the new debug levels for your session, and try again.

Either way, reading the logs should be pretty straight-forward. Open the log, scroll to the end, and scroll up slowly until you see something that looks like an error. At this point, either you'll understand what's happening, or not. If you do, you should be able to take steps to fix the problem, and if not, we would encourage you to ask a new question with the error lines and a few lines leading up to that line so we can get an idea of what's going on.

Despite cloning fixing the problem, it could still be a number of issues, such as a field that can't be seen on the layout, missing data that was fixed by a trigger or flow, data that was invalidated by a trigger or flow, or perhaps a custom child record that isn't cloned by the standard clone process. Without reading the logs, it's impossible to tell why this might be happening, so you'll need to learn a bit about logging and debugging.